# comment_template() is not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

While adding `comment_template()` to view comment box in my theme, it shows like comments are closed. i tried
 `comments_template( '', true );`
but it shows same result.and also tried
`comment_form();` but no use. Please help me

Comment: i tried comments_template();

Comment: i tried it in have_post loop. didn't work